# Sessions in PHP 7

Tags: php, session, xampp

I have been working with PHP 5.xx for years but recently updated to PHP 7. I can't create sessions.

I have read the documentation.

In earlier PHP, you just have to do:

```
session_start();
```

to start session, but this doesn't work with PHP 7 and my page keeps loading. I provided the array in the parameter too as documented on the PHP website but still it keeps loading the page.

I have tried this:

```
session_start([
'cache_limiter' => 'private',
'read_and_close' => true,
]);
```

But my browser keeps loading and after few seconds it displays 'This webpage is not available'

Apache restart errors:

> [Wed Dec 30 00:45:16.470001 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2384:tid 376] AH00455: Apache/2.4.18 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2e PHP/7.0.0 configured -- resuming normal operations
>
> [Wed Dec 30 00:45:16.470001 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2384:tid 376] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC14 Server built: Dec  9 2015 10:17:39
>
> [Wed Dec 30 00:45:16.470001 2015] [core:notice] [pid 2384:tid 376] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
>
> [Wed Dec 30 00:45:16.470001 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2384:tid 376] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 1716
>
> [Wed Dec 30 00:45:17.172064 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 1716:tid 384] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
>
> [Wed Dec 30 00:45:17.343941 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 1716:tid 384] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
>
> [Wed Dec 30 00:45:17.375192 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1716:tid 384] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.

Comment: interesting. Any errors appeared on screen / in error log ?

Comment: My tab keeps loading then after few seconds it displays 'This webpage is not available'

Comment: no logs in `error.log` ? *Assuming you're using Apache* Most of the cases of slow `session_start()` is due to failure of creating session files in specified session directory. Check also the settings to locate the session directory and make sure it has permission.

Comment: Errors: http://pastebin.com/AHK7ThVF

and I just noticed that every time I reload my webpage, it restarts Apache

Comment: The log does not show a restart.

Comment: Did you upgrade PHP5 stuff to PHP7? This is not going to work based on

http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.php

Comment: Did you upgrade the existing stack or created a new one from scratch? Did you try with a simple file just starting the session or nothing more or do you have more code and configurations in play? Which Apache, PHP7 versions, OS?

Comment: I see you're using xampp. Did you use the [official download](https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html)?

Comment: @Raptor In Apache control panel, module status changes twice.

Comment: and I download XAMPP and installed it completely from scratch, there were no installations of XAMPP before that.

Comment: I am facing same problem. Did your issue resolved?

Comment: @Shri no, I downgraded to PHP 5.x

Comment: Well it a bug of xampp which crashes apache, which is fixed in `7.0.2` and will be released soon, https://community.apachefriends.org/viewtopic.php?p=248070&sid=0b7559defe15317f41699d1ce9194e3f#p248203

Answer (score 3):

I found its a bug related to xampp version i.e. `x86 or x64` bit.
I have a system with `x64` bit windows and i installed a `xampp` with `php7` but it was `x86` bit. This was a reason for that error `apache crashes`.

Now i separately installed `apach2.4 (x64)` and `PHP7.0.1` which is working perfect now.